How to add custom message on Zod tuple?
I want to return a custom message on a Zod tuple. I did not find any way to do that.
Returned message: Array must contain at least 4 element(s)
Code:
z.tuple([
    z.enum(),
    z.number(),
    z.string(),
    z.array(),
],
    { message: "Needs to be an array." })
    //.refine, .min, .length will not work here

What I tried

There are no .min, .length arguments to do a workarround
.refine will not be called -- something else will call the message at first


The message you are refering to is not my message, it is the default message from Zod.

You can customize the error message using the errorMap property in params. Read docs here.
Here is how you would do it for your code:
z.tuple([
  z.enum(),
  z.number(),
  z.string(),
  z.array(),
], {
  errorMap: (issue, ctx) => {
    // for too_small 
    if (issue.code === z.ZodIssueCode.too_small) {
      return { message: "Missing values in tuple" };
    }

    // default message for other errors
    return { message: ctx.defaultError };
  }
})

List of zod issue codes.

Thank you soo much, I did not know i could use an error map for that. You are a genious!
